# Fastest way to log to an external server

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask, python-requests

I'm working on a python/flask application and I have my logging handled on a different server. The way I currently set it up is to have a function which sends a request to the external server whenever somebody visits a webpage.

This, of course extends my TTB because execution only continues after the request to the external server is completed. I've heard about threading but read that that also takes a little extra time.

Summary of current code:

```
log_auth_token = os.environ["log_auth"]
def send_log(data):
    post_data = {
        "data": data,
        "auth": log_auth_token
    }
    r = requests.post("https://example.com/log", data=data)

@app.route('/log')
def log():
    send_log("/log was just accessed")
    return("OK")
```

In short:

Intended behavior: User requests webpage -> User recieves response -> Request is logged.

Current behavior: User requests webpage -> Request is logged -> User recieves response.

What would be the fastest way to achieve my intended behavior?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: you seem to be asking for advice. i would personally have a dedicated thread that reads a shared queue and sends its contents to the logging server, each time a new request arrives from a used i would push that into the queue thus minimizing the wait time of the user

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the fastest way to achieve my intended behavior?

Log locally and periodically send the log files to a separate server. More specifically, you need to create rotating log files and archive them so you don't end up with 1 huge file. In order to do this you need to configure your reverse proxy (like NGINX).

Or log locally and create an application that allows you to read the log files remotely.

Sending a log per server call to a separate server simply isn't efficient unless you have another process do that. Users shouldn't have to wait for your log action to complete

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth and improved them. +1